# Makefile: conversion from recursive make calls to a sequential flow

Tags: recursion, makefile

I have a Makefile that is executed by "gmake -f Makefile foo" and looks like the following.

```
foo:

                #set var = 1
                @$(MAKE) bar var=1

bar:

                #hello.mk is included
                @echo “success”

ifeq ($(var), 1)

                include test\hello.mk

endif
```

I'd like to convert this to a sequential flow, like something in the following as it has less overhead and does not need to step back in this Makefile.

```
foo:

                $(eval var=1)
                @$(bar)

define bar

                include test\hello.mk #this doesn’t work
                @echo “success”
endef
```

I cannot have an include statement inside a function or target, so how should I go around this problem to make this Makefile sequential with no make calls?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't do this.

You want to make 'foo' and 'bar' with what are in effect different makefiles, which you can't do without a recursive call to Make.

If you can put some restrictions on what `hello.mk` can do, you might be able to get this into one pass.